# PostgreSQL generate results sequentially

Tags: postgresql, function, transactions, sequence, plpgsql

I want to give out result from a PostgreSQL database sequentially like a python Generator.
When the function get_data is called every time I want to return a new 10 rows from the rows.

I defined a sequence called `an_iter` which is increased by 10:

```
create sequence an_iter
    increment by 10;
```

My plan is to create a function that

1. increases the sequence by 10
2. return the rows which are bigger than
   sequence's current value (limit to 10)

My function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_data()
    RETURNS SETOF ppdb
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
declare
    val integer := 0;
BEGIN

    select nextval('an_iter') into val;
    Return Query SELECT * from ppdb where i<= val+10 limit 10;
END
$func$;
```

Though I called the function the same result set is returned.

Comment: `select nextval('an_iter') into val;` can be simplified to `val := nextval('an_iter');` (and that's a bit more efficient as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `BETWEEN`? Doing so you can get rid of the `LIMIT 10`, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_data()
    RETURNS SETOF ppdb
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
declare
    val integer := 0;
BEGIN

    SELECT nextval('an_iter') INTO val;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM ppdb 
                 WHERE i BETWEEN val AND val+10;
END
$func$;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=010b071aa639eb549859c428eee80a15)